# Map Inno Setup installer language to numeric codes to be stored in an INI file

Tags: installation, inno-setup, ini, pascalscript

I want to map the Inno Setup installer language to some number codes.

The code shall be stored to an INI file, like this:

```
[ini]
FileName: "{app}\lang.ini"; Section: "General"; Key: "language"; \
    String: "{code:GetLanguateID}";
```

Languages ​​corresponding to the following numbers:

english: 31
japanese: 59
german: 42
french: 37
italian: 58
korean: 66
spanish: 111
portuguese: 91

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just compare the value of the [`{language}` constant](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts&anchor=language) against the language names and return the corresponding (numeric) value:

```pascal
function GetLanguateID(Param: string): string;
begin
  case ExpandConstant('{language}') of
    'english':  Result := '31';
    'japanese': Result := '59';
    'german':   Result := '42';
    // etc...
    else RaiseException('Unexpected language');
  end;
end;
```

---

You can also achieve the same without any Pascal Script code:

```
[INI]
FileName: "{app}\lang.ini"; Section: "General"; Key: "language"; \
    String: "31"; Languages: english
FileName: "{app}\lang.ini"; Section: "General"; Key: "language"; \
    String: "59"; Languages: japanese
FileName: "{app}\lang.ini"; Section: "General"; Key: "language"; \
    String: "42"; Languages: german
; etc ...
```

To avoid repetitions, you can use preprocessor:

```
[INI]
#define MapLanguage(Language, Code) \
    "FileName: ""{app}\lang.ini""; Section: ""General""; Key: ""language""; " + \
        "String: """ + Code + """; Languages: " + Language
#emit MapLanguage("english", "31")
#emit MapLanguage("japanese", "59")
#emit MapLanguage("german", "42")
; etc ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the code you sent me worked successfully, I have spent a lot of effort to figure it out but still can't do it, thanks to your help I have reached my goal. Thank you very much again!